# Does "drawn with love" sound weird?

Tags: past-participles

I've seen people put "handmade with love" stickers on their packages. I sell art and I want to do something like that as well. 
Except I'll make a custom sticker that replaces 'handmade' with 'Drawn' or 'Painted'.

My question is, does it sound right? English isn't my first language and I'm not sure if "Drawn with Love" is grammatically correct.

Comment: It's fine. Quite normal. See [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=off&biw=1280&bih=653&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=wsFuXeb8G5Gx8gKF64aoBA&q=%22drawn+with+love%22&oq=%22drawn+with+love%22&gs_l=img.3..0i8i30.14491.15891..17347...0.0..0.77.137.2......0....1..gws-wiz-img.zrd4-4FJuog&ved=0ahUKEwjm5aWgtLXkAhWRmFwKHYW1AUUQ4dUDCAY&uact=5)

Comment: I can't really think of anything of the form *[past-tense verb] with love* that doesn't sound fine. Even something a strange like *despised with love*, while not normal, is still formed okay, and might make sense in the right context.

Answer (score 1):

"Drawn with love" is not a complete sentence, but expressions like it are often found on labels, packaging, etc.

See [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=off&biw=1280&bih=653&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=wsFuXeb8G5Gx8gKF64aoBA&q=%22drawn%20with%20love%22&oq=%22drawn%20with%20love%22&gs_l=img.3..0i8i30.14491.15891..17347...0.0..0.77.137.2......0....1..gws-wiz-img.zrd4-4FJuog&ved=0ahUKEwjm5aWgtLXkAhWRmFwKHYW1AUUQ4dUDCAY&uact=5) and [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22drawn%20with%20love%22&safe=off&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCrPaMurXkAhUSfxoKHbA6AgkQ_AUIDCgA&biw=1280&bih=653&dpr=1.5).

[image]